# insert URL Link in php built from sql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When displaying my table created from a sql query

I am attempting to change the following line which displays a table row #

```
echo $row['id'];
```

so it will insert a URL Link based on id

```
echo "<a href="/dbtest/updaterow.php?id=$row['id']>Update</a>";
```

When I do the above code, I am not getting any error in my http error log 
(Normally with syntax errors I would see them)

any help with what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

I have tried a number of iterations but each change results in a blank page being returned and no error displayed in logs.

Comment: `echo '<a href="/dbtest/updaterow.php?id="'.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to the following:

```
echo "<a href=\"/dbtest/updaterow.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Update</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change your echo to: `echo '<a href="dbtest/updaterow.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';` I hope that works if not please let me know

Comment: Thank you I performed the following `echo '<a href="/dbtest/updaterow.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';` which works for the URL, however when I try to add it to the form, using echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' id='id' value='.$row['id'].'>";
`  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /dbtest/updaterow.php on line 67    any ideas

Comment: that should be: echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">'; if that doesn't work something else is going wrong. If this is not what you ment but if you want to get the id from the url let me know

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
echo "<a href="/dbtest/updaterow.php?id=$row['id']>Update</a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='/dbtest/updaterow.php?id={$row['id']}'>Update</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<a href=\"/dbtest/updaterow.php?id=".$row['id'].">Update</a>";
```